# Painful Unity project export to Android each build (I'm doing something wrong)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, export

I would like to know if there is a faster way than the following steps to test Unity app with Android (gradle export):

1. Change something in unity
2. Build settings & Run --> Export (new Gradle)
3. Now the **old gradle** in the Android project is **replaced**, so i need to copy paste from a backup
4. The **Res folder** is also **replaced**, so I need to copy paste the backup one
5. Finally Build and Run the APK on the device

**Steps 3 and 4** are obviously what makes this process **painful (slow)**, I found the manifest.xml of the Unity android plugin, so this one stays the same (edited it directly in Unity). So am I doing something wrong ? Is there a way to **update only parts of the Android project** (like, if I only changed one line of a C# Script, just rebuild this one for Android)

Tell me if I'm not clear enough with my explanation :)

**EDIT: I Already posted this in Unity forum but I didn't get any answer yet after a day**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own Gradle file.
Put it in Plugins/Android folder and call it mainTemplate.gradle
It will use that.

As far as I know, there is no way to rebuild just part of it.
Unity does not create java files from the c# code. It creates its own modules and uses them directly.

BTW, why are you exporting at all? Why not compile directly to your device?

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I need to export the project because I'm mixing Android activities with Unity. For example I have an activity that is sending data from a background thread to Unity. I'll try your solution with the gradle (I thought Unity would just create its own gradle without any way of accessing it, each build)

Comment: The default is to create its own gradle but it will use the one you create if you wish. For the background stuff why not create an Android plugin for Unity.

Comment: Yes, the Android plugin would be a suitable solution but I'm new to Unity and I had an existing Android project, so I thought I would just export my Unity project to it. i'll take a look at Android plugins. Thanks

Comment: Look at this link for how to make a plugin: https://medium.com/@davidbeloosesky/generate-and-use-unity-plugins-3d1375c97f1b#.42u4a2gh1

Comment: Very helpful and quick, perfect

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted an additional answer for this question even though it is a bit old (just in case anyone else in the future is wondering about this like me). I personally need to make use of both Android Studio and Unity so making a plugin wasn't really an option for me.

Now I have a custom gradle file as explained in the accepted answer. However I have also added an additional resource folder (Explained well by Android here: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources.html).

You basically just have to edit your custom gradle file to add paths to both resource directories. Add the resources you don't want Unity to overwrite to the other resource folder.

Now every time you rebuild to the project the resources remain and you don't have to copy them back in.

Answer (score 0):

You can export a formal Android project first, using this project to build your final apk.
Then You could write an EditorUtil script in you Unity project, The script does following things:
1.export an temporary Android project to another folder.
2.copy assets folder and jnilib folder or any other folders you want to replace in your formal Android project.

Everytime you want export your project, just trigger the export function in you Unity Editor, It will copy and paste folders automaticlly, then your formal project will be ready for building.